# Why won't my Upstart service start after reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, ubuntu-14.04, upstart

I have a golang script I want to always be running, and it should restart on reboot.

I have a corresponding `gopush.conf` file in `/etc/init/`:

```
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid doe
setgid doe

respawn
respawn limit 5 2

exec /home/doe/test
```

I type `sudo service gopush start` and it begins running beautifully.

If I type `sudo reboot`, then ssh back in, and type `sudo service gopush status` it is always set to `stop/waiting`.

What am I doing wrong here? Why won't it start? I thought that's what the `start on...` line did?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the `filesystem` from the `start on` line?

Try using:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

Also, it will help, if you can mention which version of Ubuntu, you are using.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and I did try removing that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `start on startup` and `stop on shutdown` and is working fine on RedHat 6.8.